# Firebase vs Google Cloud SQL for Laravel

Tags: sql, database, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I've already read a lot about it, but I'm particularly interested for Laravel and its price difference.

We run a web application based on Laravel and this already with the Google Cloud App Engine. For our web application we need a solid database. Here the question arose, which one?

What are the main differences between Firebase and GCP SQL? How is this reflected in the price?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd recommend heading into [this GCP Databases page](https://cloud.google.com/products/databases/) which has a cool matrix on what are the differences between solutions on GCP. It really depends on what kind of data you have and how scalable the solution needs to be.

There is also a nice decision diagram on [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/this-week-in-google-cloud-a-db-storage-decision-tree-a-python-upgrade-a-new-ca-and-still-more-1a653c63d881) which can be seen below. It feels like instead of using Firebase Realtime DB or Cloud Datastore, one should now be using the [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) which is also integrated into the GCP UI experience.

[image]